# Split pandas dataframe into multiple dataframes with list of lists as mask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe tat looks something like this

```
A BB
1 foo.bar
2 foo.bar
3 foo.foo
4 foo.bar
5 foo.bar
6 foo.foo
```

I basically expect to get two dataframes out of them based on this list of lists:

```
[[False, False, True], [False, False, True]]
```

OUTPUT should be:

**df1:**

```
A BB
1 foo.bar
2 foo.bar
3 foo.foo
```

**df2**

```
A BB
4 foo.bar
5 foo.bar
6 foo.foo
```

Comment: What do the Booleans do?

Comment: @fsimonjetz not really very important i intend to add them as a column once I am able to get these splits, basically I am splitting it at foo.foo the booleans are a product of that

Comment: I see, so you want to split at lines following a `foo.foo`?

Comment: @fsimonjetz yes that is accurate

Comment: If the list is `[[False, False], [True, False, False, True]]`, you will have df1 with 2 rows and df2 with 4 rows?

Comment: @Corralien yes that is the expectation, but it should not happen as I want to split it after foo.foo basically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy:

- `flatnonzero` to find where the `'foo.foo'` rows are
- `split` to divide the dataframe up accordingly

---

```
import numpy as np

np.split(df, np.flatnonzero(df.BB.eq('foo.foo'))[:-1] + 1)

[   A       BB
 0  1  foo.bar
 1  2  foo.bar
 2  3  foo.foo,
    A       BB
 3  4  foo.bar
 4  5  foo.bar
 5  6  foo.foo]
```

---

Addressing [@mozway's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71697964/split-pandas-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes-with-list-of-lists-as-mask/71698343#comment126712380_71698343) comment

```
list(filter(
    lambda d: not d.empty,
    np.split(df, np.flatnonzero(df.BB.eq('foo.foo')) + 1)
))

[   A       BB
 0  1  foo.bar
 1  2  foo.bar
 2  3  foo.foo,
    A       BB
 3  4  foo.bar
 4  5  foo.bar
 5  6  foo.foo]
```

Comment: wow that's some seriously nice piece of code

Comment: Nice, but the `[:-1]` seems a bit non general. This wouldn't work if the last item isn't foo. The`cumsum` is more robust IMO.

Comment: @mozway you are correct.  You could instead `np.split(df, np.flatnonzero(df.BB.eq('foo.foo')) + 1)` and filter out empty dataframes from the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can

- get the rows where `df.BB` equals `'foo.foo'`
- shift that by one row
- apply cumulative sum to that and
- group by the resulting indices.

You end up with a `groupby` object that you can turn into a list of sub-dfs.

```py
>>> groups = df.groupby(df.BB.eq('foo.foo').shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())
>>> frames = [frame for _, frame in groups]
>>> frames # list of sub-dfs
[   A       BB
 0  1  foo.bar
 1  2  foo.bar
 2  3  foo.foo,
    A       BB
 3  4  foo.bar
 4  5  foo.bar
 5  6  foo.foo]
```

Comment: awesome shift is a great idea, i prefer to do ```dict(tuple(groups))``` though

Comment: @Inder I figured in this case the group labels returned by `cumsum()` are pretty much meaningless, but sure, `dict()` works as well!

Comment: `dict((*df.groupby(df.BB.eq('foo.foo').iloc[::-1].cumsum()),))`

Comment: @piRSquared I see, applying `cumsum()` to the reversed rows gets rid of the need to `shift`... I learned another clever technique, thank you!

Comment: Clever, maybe.  Not sure if it's better.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you expect:

```
m = len(df) // 2
df1, df2 = df.iloc[:m], df.iloc[m:]
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
   A       BB
0  1  foo.bar
1  2  foo.bar
2  3  foo.foo

>>> df2
   A       BB
3  4  foo.bar
4  5  foo.bar
5  6  foo.foo
```

Or use [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)

```
df1, df2 = np.split(df, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer but the length is not significant here it was just an example

Comment: You just want to split at each iteration of `foo.foo`?

Comment: yes that is correct