# pandas: read multiple dataframes from one csv

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, read.csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
col A, col B
1, 5
2,7
78,65
###########
5,8
15,23
###########
17, 15
25,62
12,15
95,56
```

How to transform it into set of dataframes, one for each area between ######### lines (I can change the marker if needed)?

The result should be something like this:

```
df1 = {col A :{1,2,78}, col B: {5,7,65}}
df2 = {col A: {5,15}, col B: {8,23}}
df3 = {col A: {17,25,12,95}, col B: {15,62,15,56}}
```

I know there is a workaround using file.readlines(), but it is "not very elegant" - I wonder if there is a pandas way to do it directly.

Comment: You read the file as text and you split at `#####`. Now you have a list of strings. You create a `io.StringIO` https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o and you pass such "file" to pandas `read_csv()` (note: pandas doc cite StringIO, but without explanation it)

Answer (score 0):

Highly inspired by piRSquared's answer [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71698343/16120011), you can approach your goal like this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("/input_file.csv")

# is the row a horizontal delimiter ?
m = df["col A"].str.contains("#", na=False)

l_df = list(filter(lambda d: not d.empty, np.split(df, np.flatnonzero(m) + 1)))

_ = [exec(f"globals()['df{idx}'] = df.loc[~m]") for idx, df in enumerate(l_df, start=1)]
#if you need a dictionary (instead of a dataframe), you can use df.loc[~m].to_dict("list")
```

NB : We used [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html?highlight=globals#globals) to create the variables/sub-dataframes dynamically.

###### # Output :

```
print(df1, type(df1)), print(df2, type(df2)), print(df3, type(df3))

  col A   col B
0     1     5.0
1     2     7.0
2    78    65.0 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

  col A   col B
4     5     8.0
5    15    23.0 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

   col A   col B
7     17    15.0
8     25    62.0
9     12    15.0
10    95    56.0 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```